# Jmeter only runs the first thread

Tags: jmeter

I'm still new to Jmeter and I'm having trouble running more than one thread in my test plan.

I'm trying to run the tests using the GUI (just to make check that they pass), but when I run the test plan, it only seems to run the first thread in the plan. Is there something I've done wrong in my test plan?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should show details of your Thread Groups and CSV Data Set Configs - there is not much one can see from the general plan

Comment: Plan defines thread groups, not threads, while threads are defined per thread group. So do you mean that only first thread group (Pause Resume) runs? Or do you mean that you configured thread group to run multiple threads, but only one runs? In either case, more details are needed: plan configuration, thread group configuration, View Result Tree screenshot to begin with...

Comment: I did mean the thread groups, only the first one gets run. I've added some screenshots of the test plan, thread groups and result tree.

Answer (score 0):

Add "View result tree" listener in your test plan level instead of adding it individually for each thread group. This will solve your issue.

[image]

Hope this helps..